# Heroku grails app fail to connect to mysql RDS "wrong scheme in URI"

Tags: mysql, grails, heroku, rds

I want to connect to mysql RDS instance from java/grails application.
And I am getting this kind of error:

```
[main] ERROR heroku.HerokuBeanPostprocessor - Problem updating DataSource: wrong scheme in URI: mysql://USER:PASSWORD@q-qa-dev.cctpl5gym4kp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/qservice_dev
2012-08-14T15:23:33+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong scheme in URI: mysql://USER:PASSWORD@q-qa-dev.cctpl5gym4kp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/qservice_dev
```

I can connect with "heroku sql" and make requests to the DB with no problem.